# Scan app for Samsung SCX-4100

Tags: 14.10, samsung, scanner

Trying to get a scanner app or program or anything for my Samsung SCX-4100 to scan onto Ubuntu 14.10.

Have tried 6 of the scanner programs, but they cannot see the scanner. It works OK with Windows!

As a printer, it works fine with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
wget http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/pool/debian/extra/su/suldr-keyring_2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i suldr-keyring_2_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install suld-driver-4.00.39
```

In the driver deb configuration file select the user(s) that need to be added to the lp group in order to be able to use the scan.

You will need to log out and in again.

Comment: Just tested in Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome Edition: log out and log in was not needed.

Comment: Worked for ubuntu 19.04, does NOT work for ubuntu 14.04 though (therefore only one uplike from me :)

Comment: Installed the above driver on ubuntu 22.04 and tested with document scanner. It recognizes that it is a samsung scx4100. When I press the green scan however I get an error saying unable to scan.
Even after a restart. Any Idea what I can do?

Comment: I used this driver: https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/driver/UnifiedLinuxDriver-1.00.21.tar.gz and it worked for me under ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be [Launchpad bug #1026159](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-frontends/+bug/1026159). A commenter on the bug tracker [suggests a workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-frontends/+bug/1026159/comments/2):

> Open a terminal and type:
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
> ```
>
> At the end of the file copy/paste these two lines, save and exit:
>
> ```
> # Samsung SCX-4100
> usb 0x04e8 0x3413
> ```
>
> Now the same for the second file. From terminal type:
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
> ```
>
> Now, NOT at the end of the file as earlier, but around row 832, close
>   to `Samsung scx-4200`, add the following two rows:
>
> ```
> # Samsung SCX-4100
> ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3413", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
> ```
>
> Save, close […].

Restart the `saned` daemon:

```
sudo service saned restart
```

> Scanner should be ready to be used.

(I changed `sudo gedit` to the saner `gksudo gedit` and removed the unnecessary reboot in favour of a daemon restart.)

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 that's no longer neither needed nor enough. Download the suld-driver-4.00.39 driver from  http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html, as indicated in the bug report...

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, here's a [detailed outline](https://askubuntu.com/a/1373625/1519106) of how to enable network scanning for **Samsung SCX-4729FW** under **Ubuntu 18.04**. The scanner can then be used from SANE (Simple Scan), basically, similar to ScanToPC.

While this could be set up with `sane-xerox_mfp` backend (by simply adding a `tcp <printer's-IP-address> 9400` entry), this would not work properly when scanning from ADF Feeder. Instead, the current solution that worked for me involves installing the scanner driver from the official Unified Linux driver package for the printer (**uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz**, only scanner part `./install-scanner.sh`), fixing up some links to the dirver's `libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1`, installing legacy libusb version (`libusb-0.1-4`), and finally, adding the printer's USB info (`usb 0x04e8 0x3453`) in `xerox_mfp.conf`.

The scanner is then being recognized as `smfp:net;<printer's-IP-address>` device.

Well, it works now! Wish it worked without such involved configuration.