# How to setup Samsung M2070FW network scanner

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, scanner, samsung

Did anyone make Samsung M2070FW All-in-one's scanner work over the network? I'm in my local network in my house. I use Kubuntu 18.04. The printer is connected directly to the router via RJ45 cable, it has static IP. I installed the official drivers from the HP website - I could add a printer over the network but I can't seem to figure out the way I could make scanning work as well. I know that there are solutions involving `sane` but I believe there are much simpler methods out there.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify if the printer/scanner is being used wirelessly or attached to your router by USB cable or similar.

Comment: @chili555 please find my edited question

Comment: I know precisely nothing about scanners. I suspect, based on my zero experience, that sane is required, however.

Comment: Scanning typically does NOT work over the network. Some semi-pro or pro MFPs can save the scanned image to a previously configured network share. This is not the same as using a local app to scan from a network connected device.

Comment: My printer/scanner Samsung M2070 is connected through Wi-Fi, and my Ubuntu is 18.04 (Bionic)
I have found a tutorial in french: 
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org//tutoriel/installer_imprimante_samsung

The main point is to edit 2 files, so as to add the following:

/etc/sane.d/xerox-mfp.conf
#Samsung M2070 Series
usb 0x04e8 0x3469
tcp 192.168.1.35 (the ip address of the printer/scanner)

/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules
# Samsung M2070
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3469", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia well, the Windows driver for this printer obviously CAN do that

Comment: @DominikCornice That worked! Thank you! Please, post it as an answer, I will happily mark it as accepted

Comment: @DominikCornice Hmm... your suggestion made Skanlite detect my printer but when I click scan or preview it doesn't receive any feedback it just stucks

Comment: You can use Simple Scan too. First time it stucked at my end, I had to adjust to lower resolution. Maybe someone will improve that. My challenge was to prove it can work. I have better results with Windows.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia our Canon MFP scans just fine over the network. Accessible to any networked device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I installed the scanner for Samsung-M2070FW on several devices with Ubuntu 18.04. Of course both devices (printer/scanner and Ubuntu client) had to be in the same network. Here is how I did it:

1. Download `UnifiedLinuxDriver-1.00.37` from https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suld.html
2. Extract archive and go to script folder: `cd UnifiedLinuxDriver-1.00.37/uld/`
3. Call install script with `sudo ./install` Answer questions with "Yes"
4. Install Libusb: `sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4`
5. Link Libsane-Library from the installed archive to the right place: `sudo ln -s /opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1`
6. Change Firewall rules and restart services:

   ````
   sudo ufw allow 22161
   sudo service ufw stop
   sudo service saned stop
   sudo service ufw start
   sudo service saned start```
   ````
7. Start scan program with `simple-scan`

If it doesn't work for some reasons, there are debugging options. For Simple Scan, you can call it with debugging on: `simple-scan -d`. To see the error messages from Sane, you start it with: `sudo export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=255 && scanimage -L > debug.txt` That will dump the debug information in a file called `debug.txt`.

Comment: What does `sudo ufw allow 22161` do? It opens some port in the firewall but what does this port do?

Comment: I'm not sure :) I analyzed the traffic from the printer. But I googled now and found this: "Scanner can not be found via 
network: For some Linux distributions, strong firewall is enabled and it may block our installer from opening necessary port for searching 
network devices. In such case, open snmp port - 22161 manually or disable the firewall temporarily while using the device." [source](https://www.manualshelf.com/manual/samsung/sl-m2070fw-xaa/user-manual-ver10/page-263.html)

Answer (score 4):

My printer/scanner Samsung M2070 is connected through Wi-Fi, and my Ubuntu is 18.04 (Bionic).
I have found a tutorial in french:

http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org//tutoriel/installer_imprimante_samsung

The main point is to edit 2 files, so as to add the following:

1. /etc/sane.d/xerox-mfp.conf

```
# Samsung M2070 Series

usb 0x04e8 0x3469
tcp 192.168.1.35 (the ip address of the printer/scanner)
```

2. /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules

```
# Samsung M2070
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3469", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Comment: I have another computer running 14.04 on the same LAN. I had absolutely nothing to do to have it scan with the same printer/scanner.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with the M2070FW on Ubuntu 19.10. The scanner was detected, and `scanimage -L` detected the scanner, but when scanning with `scanimage --format jpg > test.jpg` I got the error message "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00". I tried a [lot of](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1724078) [different](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012) [things](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane_Troubleshooting#The_symlink_and_udev_tricks), but the solution in the end was to install libusb-0.1-4. This is because the Samsung / HP smfp driver needs libsub-0.1-4 to load (while only libusb-1.0-0 is installed). You see this (only) when running `export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=255 && scanimage -L`:

> ...
>   [dll] load: searching backend 'smfp' in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
>   [dll] load: trying to load '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1'
>   [dll] load: dlopen() failed (libusb-0.1.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
>   ...

If you can now scan with `scanimage`, but not the GUI version `simple-scan`, make sure sane is not loading the xerox_mfp driver. You can see this by running `simple-scan -d` from the command line. If it says:

> DEBUG: scanner.vala:867: sane_open ("xerox_mfp:tcp 192.168.47.30
>   9400") -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD

Then make sure you edit `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` and comment out the line mentioning your printer to prevent sane from loading the xerox_mfp driver for it:

```
#Samsung M2070FW
#tcp 192.168.47.30 9400
```

You might need to reboot or uninstall and install the printer driver again. When running `simple-scan -d` again now it should say:

> DEBUG: scanner.vala:867: sane_open ("smfp:net;192.168.47.30") ->
>   SANE_STATUS_GOOD

and scanning should work.

Comment: This answer contains more useful info than anything else on the net in the 7 years since. Shame that it is so low. This is what you should look at to make your Samsung MFP work (C480fw here).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone tries to setup network (ScanToPC) scanning with a Samsung SCX-4729FW MFP (set up on the network via Wi-Fi) under Ubuntu 18.04. Here's what worked for me.

Initially, I only set up the network printing (added a printer by its IP using the default Ubuntu's 'Samsung SCX-472x Series PXL' driver). Printing worked well. However, scanning did not work. SANE (Simple Scan) would not find any scanners.

After reading through numerous links and trying various settings (including installing the official Unified Linux driver from the HP/Samsung site, 'uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz'). Scanner was still not visible.

Eventually, I tried to configure the `tcp` setting in `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf` with printer's IP address and port 9400. THIS time it worked! To make it less cryptic, I added printer's IP to `/etc/hosts` so it could be referred to as `scx4729fw`.

I uninstalled the official Unified Samsung's driver and the scanning works without it. Apparently, the installed Ubuntu's printer/scanner drivers are sufficient. **The key change in this case is the `tcp` setting with the correct port (9400).**

Here's the specific changes in `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf`:

1. Add the following  setting for `Samsung SCX-4729FW` (similarly how it's done for `SCX-4500W`) into `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf`

```
# Samsung SCX-4729FW, network mode
tcp scx4729fw 9400
```

2. Add an entry into your `/etc/hosts` for your, if needed:

```
scx4729fw  <printer's IP address>
```

3. Test if the scanner is being recognized:

```
scanimage -L
```

Output:

```
device `xerox_mfp:tcp scx4729fw 9400' is a Samsung SCX-472x Series multi-function peripheral
```

4. Now the scanner is also usable from SANE (Simple Scan).

If it still does not work, try the debugging step outlined above.

Thanks to @[Bim](https://askubuntu.com/users/610679/bim) for pointing in the right direction!

---

**UPDATE**: The setup above does not seem to work properly with ADF (Automatic Document Feeder, which is simplex/non-duplex in this model). Only the first page is scanned, while the remaining pages are just fed through without scanning. This also results in either *"Document feeder out of documents"* `scanimage` message for Page 2, or *"Device I/O"* error in `Simple-Scan`, after which the device needs a power-cycled to be recognized again.

Lengthy search and analysis led me to the following solution:

- Install the official Unified Linux driver for the SCX-4729FW: **`uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tag.gz`** (`./install-scanner.sh`)
- Create links to the dirver's `libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1`

```
sudo ln -s /opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so
```

- Install a legacy libusb version: `libusb-0.1-4`

```
sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4
```

- Add USB info (vendorID, productID) for the SCX-4729FW into `/etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf`; comment out the network mode 'tcp' setting:

```
# Samsung SCX-4729FW
usb 0x04e8 0x3453

# Samsung SCX-4729FW, network mode
#tcp scx4729fw 9400
```

- Test the scanner detection via the Unified Linux driver's `smfp` SANE backed:

```
scanimage -L

Output:
device `smfp:net;<printer's-IP-address>' is a Samsung SCX-472x Series on <printer's-IP-address> Scanner
```

- You may also need to add your user to either `lpadmin` or `lp` group to give permission to use the scanner device (check `groups`)

Now the scanner should also be usable in `Simple-Scan` and properly scanning 'All Pages From Feeder'.

It's not clear what causes the abort in `sane-xerox_mfp` backend after the first page scanned from ADF. Indeed this issue is widely reported. I believe it should be possible to figure this out so that no proprietary driver and legacy `libusb` version would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am using a samsung M2070 printer and scanner. I managed to get the printer working by selecting IPP in the new printer dialog.

For the scanner I installed [`sane-airscan`](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) and then `xsane` and `scanimage -L` detected the scanner using WSD.

I compiled from source. Required packages for me were `libgnutls28-dev` and `libsane-dev`. Others were possibly already installed. `make && sudo make install` were all that was required for the scanner to show up.

More resources [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SaneOverNetwork).