# 18.04 and Samsung: Scan to PC not available

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, scanner, samsung

I'm using Samsung XPress 2070FW over WiFi and I cannot get the printer to scan using the on-the-printer scan to pc function. The error message is "Scan to PC not available". However, scanning using the PC (sane) works fine. The driver is the unified one for the model, but there's no interface like the one of windows so I cannot tweak scanning on Ubuntu.

Anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: How does "scan to PC" works in Windows in the same network environment? Did you have to select a shared network folder? If so you may try doing the same in Ubuntu (creating the samba share with the required permissions) and then adjust for that in the printer. If this step can't be done in the printer itself you may need to use a Windows PC with the printer's drivers.

Comment: Ignore the windows comment, it was a reference to the troubleshooting tips provided by Samsung's website.

Comment: It makes sense, not the only one with a setup tool in Windows without equivalent in Linux. But the question remains: How does it scan to PC from network? Can you select where to send the image file? If not, are you able to set a network location in the scanner?

Comment: There's only the option "Scan to PC" and Scan to WDS. None of them work, you can't get past that.

Comment: You can't use this feature unless the vendor provides Linux software for it.

Comment: maybe [this](https://jronnholm.sysio.se/scan-with-samsung-c480w-over-network-from-mint/)  could help ?

Comment: You've probably already read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116233/how-to-setup-samsung-m2070fw-network-scanner

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to ask HP to release an application similar to Windows for Linux. This is a good place to start:

- [HP Developers - HP Linux printing and scanning](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing)

[image: hplip website.png]

In this **Ask Ubuntu** [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) it is asked:

- What should one install to make Ubuntu fully support the HP printer and/or scanner?

The answer there is to use:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui
```

*However the full answer is **more complicated** than just the simple command*

---

If you can't get help direct from HP you can try using `wine` to run the Windows application inside Linux:

- [How to Use a Printer Through Wine](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-printer-through-wine-56744.html)

Answer (score 1):

If yo're using the Bchemnet repository and the sane library. You can follow my steps.

1. Open terminal and run

   ```
   sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-smfp* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
   ```
2. Edit the file *some_samsung.rules* ,you can find in */etc/udev/rules.d* folder, and then include Samsung Model Numbers using `ATTRS(idProduct)=="2070", ENV(libsane_matched)="yes"`

Finally restart your system.